# c# get system volume level in windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, windows-phone, volume, windows-10-mobile

How can I get the volume level in Windows 10 Mobile. I need some API? But, I can't find this. Just what I need, it's have event when volume button pressed or volume changed.

Answer (score 0):

The current Windows Phone SDK doesn't allow you to subscribe to any volume pressed event.Hopefully this is possible in the future SDK released.